# how to enable mypages on dd-wrt?

Tags: linux, router, dd-wrt

i have a: Buffalo WHR-300HP2, with: Firmware Version DD-WRT v24SP2- (11/05/13) std - build 22750, on: Kernel Version Linux 3.10.18 #37 Tue Nov 5 08:17:35 CET 2013 mips.

i am trying to use [mypage](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/MyPage), it apparently needs [jffs](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/JFFS).

a related [post](https://superuser.com/questions/962351/jffs-partition-for-dd-wrt-yes-or-no) suggests these [instructions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Journalling_Flash_File_System#Directions_for_.28normal.29_users:_using_Web-GUI_Interface), but neither firefox or chrome show the jffs support on the administration|management page (but there is a line: `show_layer_ext(document.setup.enable_jffs2, 'idjffs2', 0 == 1);` in the source for that page.

i did an `nvram set enable_jffs2=1`, and `nvram show | grep jffs` says: enable_jffs2=1. i restarted the browser, bit still no jffs support in the web page.

edit: did an `nvram commit` and cycled power on the router, still no joy :(

thanks

Comment: Did you read [this thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=415599)? Might have some directions on how to enable. Seems like there's a different build for JFFS support.

Comment: i have v24SP2- (11/05/13) std - build 22750 and the browser shows: Use JFFS2 for client lease DB on the services page (but it is unchecked).

Comment: it says here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Changelog#v24_SP2_.28preview_release.29 that v23 has jffs2.

Comment: Is this one of those Buffalo routers that come with dd-wrt loaded at the factory, or did you install it yourself? The reason why I ask is that I, too, was unable to enable jffs2 support on a factory installed dd-wrt (unintended pun, unable/enable, sorry).

Comment: it's stock, off the shelf:  v24SP2- (11/05/13) std - build 22750. did you try: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Journalling_Flash_File_System#Directions_for_.28normal.29_users:_using_Web-GUI_Interface